# progressView doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

i want to show a progressView when the app is launching (with the splash screen) so, in the **appDelegate .h file** i declared a progressView :

```
UIProgressView *progView;
```

and in the **appDelegate .m file** i did this :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    sleep(1);



    progView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
    progView.progress = 0.75f;


// the rest..
}
```

i didn't see the progress bar in the splash screen, help please, thx in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot influence the splash screen itself, it's only a static image.

What you can do however is to let your app load until you get the delegate message, then fire up some basic UI which shows your progress view and then do some heavy startup process in a background thread, updating your progress bar accordingly. When the thread has finished its work, call back to the main thread to start the real application.

**Edit**: Updated my answer to clarify some things

The application startup in iOS happens basically in 2 phases.

1. The operating system launches your application, the app sets up basic stuff, starts the run loop, etc. During this time the splash screen is shown. During this phase the application is not under the control of the programmer.
2. `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called. In this method you as a programmer may do some startup tasks, such as loading the database, connecting to some service, etc. During this phase you can influence the user interface and also show for example a progress bar. If you need to do this, create a background thread and do the setup work there.

Note: It does not work if you just put a progress bar on the UI and then do some stuff in the `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, since the UI is not shown until **after** this method has returned. That's why you need to do the setup in a background thread.

Comment: i didn't understand what you mean by "do some heavy startup process in a background thread"

Comment: The time the operating system needs to load your application, open the main XIB, setting up the delegate, etc. is when you will see the splash screen. After this the operating system passes control to your app by calling didFinishLaunching. If you have anything to setup from this point on which takes time, do it in a background thread and show the progess bar. If you don't have such a setup the progress bar will not help the user.

Comment: thx for your explanation, but what i did is in the didFinishLaunching method, am i wrong ?? or didn't understand clearly yet ??

Comment: 1. loading (with splash screen) 2. whatever is in your didFinishLaunching method - this could be logic for loading your app (where it seems like a good idea to put up some sort of message to the user that you are indeed loading) or loading a view and its values. anyway, whatever is in your `didFinishLoadingWithOptions` method will be done before a view is shown. if you want to load a splash screen as a view, you should do your logic in the views own delegate methods

Comment: should i program a method in the appDelegate.m something like that ?? actually i need to show the progress bar simultaneously with the splash screen

Comment: @Malek: I updated my answer to point a few things out more clearly. Basically what you need is a background thread which does the work, not a method which is just called from the app delegate.

Comment: really thx for your explanation, but last question, what you mean by "background process" ??

Comment: Sorry, by background process I mean a separate thread. Fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

is that all the code for progView? Cuz you haven't added it as a subview to anything, so how would you be able to see it? You need something like:

```
[splashView addSubview:progView];
```

frenetisch gave some reasonable explanation of the startup process of an IOS app, but it sounds like  you need to do some basic investigation into this. It generally takes very little time before your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called and you can show your first view. But what things do you then need to do before your app is actually usable? You want to show a progress view so there must be SOMETHING that you plan to do that takes some time. It's while THAT is going on you need to show the progress view and somehow update it's progress.